# Correct meaning of SecondActivity.class in intents in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, reflection

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startService(intent);
```

What i understood is, till this line of code "SecondActivity object" is not created and we are sending Runtime data of SecondActivity to Intent. So, what i think is at runtime compiler adds some extra code to second Activity.

I know this is related to Reflection but still i don't understand correctly. Does ".class" denotes a "static Variable class" of type "Class" in "SecondActivity" class at runtime, something like,

```
static Class class = .......
```

Are we accessing Class object through "class static Variable"? Does compiler at runtime adds this static variable through which we are getting "Class object" of SecondActivity? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: SecondActivity.class denotes Instances of the class Class. Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader. 

It's used in Intent#setClass(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) as convenience for calling Intent#setComponent(ComponentName) with the name returned by a Class object.

Comment: @YggdrJerycho Thanks! Do you mean "SecondActivity.class" as a whole is Class Object and there is no static variable created at runtime?

Comment: There are static fields of type Class named class constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader. As described in documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, it's "what *is* SecondActivity.class?" and/or "what is .class?"

Although this isn't *necessarily* an Android question, I understand the context and will concede that it could be interpreted as such.

Essentially, ".class" refers to a class which (in your example) is an implrmentation of an Android Service, such that calling `startService(intent)` will create an Object instance from that class and set it up as a service.

The actual `SecondActivity.class` can be thought of as a constant reference to the class "SecondActivity". This is all managed by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

This means that calling the `SecondActivity.class` as kind of static variable is almost right, except that it's more of a static *constant* since it will always refer to a class called `SecondActivity` that either is, or will be loaded into memory.

**Advanced explanation:**

The class reference will cause a call to the current ClassLoader to get or load the referred class. If the class hasn't been loaded, it is instantiated and the `static{}` code block is called. Only one instance of this class can exist per ClassLoader and depending on which ClassLoader you are using, it may decide to check if any parent ClassLoaders already have the class loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, though i couldn't understand your advanced explanation. Can you give some resources, such as books or any online references,  which provide more info on this?

Comment: Of course! http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html   http://javarevisited.blogspot.se/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html?m=1    To summarize the articles: Classes are the representations of the code you create. A ClassLoader basically has the task of taking Java bytecode (like what you find in .class files) and putting it in the memory of your computer so that it can be used in the program.

Answer (score -3):

Write it as

```html
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startService(intent);
```

This means that you are refering  to second Activity which is not created yet so you are using its class file to load class in memory

Comment: YourActivity.this is to access outerclass object from InnerClass but this is not my question. My question is about understanding of ".class" or "SecondActivity.class".

Comment: You answer is not at all related to my question. I don't know why you said to use YourActivity.this as  my question is no where related to OnClickListeners or any innerclasses. My question is about understanding of  ".class or SecondActivity.class". Please read my question again.

Comment: Actually, in this case, SecondActivity must extend Service for the above code not to generate an error. Thus, it is not an Activity. In addition to this, the class file may already be loaded (say, for instance if the class has been referenced earlier). The statement `SecondActivity.class` is just requesting a Class object referring to SecondActivity, whether it's loaded or not